# set layout gravity to right

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I would like to set gravity to right of my layout but it does not works fine :
(below codes are inside a loop)

```
        LinearLayout lin  = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        LayoutParams lin_parms = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lin_parms.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        lin.setLayoutParams(lin_parms);
        lin.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        LayoutParams txt_parms = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        txt_parms.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;


        TextView txt_view = new TextView(getActivity());
        txt_view.setLayoutParams(txt_parms);
        txt_view.setTypeface(font);
        txt_view.setText("hello");

        lin.addView(txt_view);

        lay_lin_list_tractions.addView(lin);
```

[image]

Comment: did you tried setting layout_gravity ="right" ?

Comment: Is not clear what did you expect. Please explain the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `TextView` params as `WRAP_CONTENT`

```
LayoutParams txt_parms = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```